# If $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ are linearly dependent vectors and $v_2$, $v_3$, $v_4$ linearly independent vectors, then prove the following.

Tags: vectors

If $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ are linearly dependent vectors and $v_2$, $v_3$, $v_4$ linearly independent vectors, show that 

i) $v_1$ is a linear combination of $v_2$ and $v_3$ 
ii)$v_4$ is not a linear combination of $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$

As $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ are dependent, I am logically able to comprehend that $v_1$ can be expressed as in terms of $c_1$$v_2$ + $c_2$$v_3$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are some constants. However, I am unable to prove it. As for the ii) sub-part, I do not know where to begin.

Comment: What did you manage to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i) By definition, if the set $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly dependent, there exists scalars $(x_1,x_2,x_3)\neq(0,0,0)$ such that
\begin{equation}
x_1v_1+x_2v_2+x_3v_3=0
\end{equation}
So then
\begin{equation}
x_1v_1=-x_2v_2-x_3v_3    
\end{equation}
Our goal is to prove that $x_1 \neq 0$. By contradiction, suppose $x_1=0$. That means that, at least, $x_2\neq 0$ or $x_3\neq 0$. Without loss of generality, assume that $x_2\neq0$. Then, from the above expression, we get
\begin{equation}
0= -x_2v_2-x_3v_3
\end{equation}
Which show that, as $x_2 \neq 0$, the set $\{v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly dependent. But then, again as $x_2 \neq 0$, we can show that

\begin{equation}
0= -x_2v_2-x_3v_3+0\cdot v_4
\end{equation}
Which implies that the set $\{v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is linearly dependent, which is a contradiction. Thus $x_1 \neq 0$ and we can simplify on the first equation and show that

\begin{equation}
v_1=-\frac{x_2}{x_1}v_2-\frac{x_3}{x_1}v_3    
\end{equation}

ii) Again, by contradiction, suppose 4 is a linear combination of 1, 2, 3. As proven before, $v_1$ is a linear combination of $v_2, v_3$, what implies we can express it in terms of $v_2$ and $v_3$, so in the end, we get that there exist scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that:
\begin{equation}
v_4=\alpha v_2+\beta v_3    
\end{equation}
This clearly implies that the set $\{v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is linearly dependent, which is a contradiction. Thus, 4 is not a linear combination of 1, 2, 3.

Comment: @EgorIvanov actually thanks to the condition imposed to $v_2, v_3, v_4$, the first statement is true. Otherwise, it would not be true, as you outlined in your counterexample

Comment: oh, really, I see, the second condition is sufficient, good solution!

Answer (score 0):

i) statement is false, check the example:
$$\textbf{v}_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \textbf{v}_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, \textbf{v}_3=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$
They are linear dependent:
$$0\cdot \textbf{v}_1 + 2\cdot \textbf{v}_2 - \textbf{v}_3 = \boldsymbol 0$$
But it can be easily seen that $\textbf{v}_1$ can't be equal to a linear combination of $\textbf{v}_2$ and $\textbf{v}_3$

**UPD:** The solution does not use the second condition, that is sufficient, so the counter example above is wrong, check the solution below